# How do I test that a Rails Helper defines a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, helper

I am creating a Rails plugin and it is dynamically adding a method to a Helper. I just want to ensure that the method is added. How can I see if the Helper responds to the method name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
def test_that_foo_helper_defines_bar
  o = Object.new
  assert !o.respond_to? :bar
  o.extend FooHelper
  assert o.respond_to? :bar
end
```